# Static C# list keeps growing in size after each iteration

Tags: c#, arrays, json, arraylist, static

I'm currently trying to debug a program that runs every 5 minutes. My main issue is trying to find the reason why a static list keeps growing in size every time my program runs. The goal is to keep this list the same size but update it's items with different values every time it executes.

Below is the code for the class that is running every 5 minutes and setting the values for a json message that I am sending to rabbitmq.

The method `PushJsonToBroker()` is where I found the issue of the `compDataList` growing in size after each execution.

```
class Program
{
        private static List<SimulatedData> compDataList = new List<SimulatedData>();

        public static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            var autoEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
            var stateTime = new Timer(SimulateData, autoEvent, 1000, 300000);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static void SimulateData(object state)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n" + DateTime.Now + "\nSimulating Data...");
            List<string> compValueList = new List<string>();
            compValueList = ReadCompValueRow();
            CompChannelValueMatching(compValueList);
            PushJsonToBroker();
        }

        public static void CompChannelValueMatching(List<string> compValueList)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Matching values with channels for Compressor...");
                foreach(var c in compChannelListMongo)
                {
                    string value;
                    string units;
                    string simTag;
                    string name;
                    var channelIndexMongo = compChannelListMongo.IndexOf(c);
                    if (c.Equals("C1"))
                    {
                        value = compValueList.ElementAt<string>(0);
                        units = compUnitListMongo.ElementAt<string>(channelIndexMongo);
                        simTag = compTagListMongo.ElementAt<string>(channelIndexMongo);
                        name = compNameListMongo.ElementAt<string>(channelIndexMongo);
                        decimal num, x;
                        if (decimal.TryParse(value, out x))
                        {
                            num = x;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            num = 0;
                        }
                        SetCompValues(units, simTag, name, num);
                    }
               }
               catch (Exception ex)
               {
                   Console.WriteLine(ex);
               }
        }

    public static void SetCompValues(string units, string simTag, string name, decimal num)
    {
        compDataList.Add(new SimulatedData { units = units, tag = simTag, name = name, value = num });
    }

    public static void PushJsonToBroker()
    {
        List<string> thingList = new List<string>();
        List<string> assetTypeList = new List<string>();
        Simulator.JsonProps data = new Simulator.JsonProps();
        DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;
        var dateValue = dateTime.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss.ffffff");
        var demoThings = DBConnect.CosmosClient.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("Things");

        foreach (var doc in demoThings.Find(x => x["_id"] != "").ToList())
        {
            thingList.Add(doc["_id"].ToString());
            assetTypeList.Add(doc["AssetType"].ToString());
        }
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nCreating Json...");
            foreach (var thingNo in thingList)
            {
                var thingIndex = thingList.IndexOf(thingNo);
                var assetType = assetTypeList.ElementAt<string>(thingIndex);
                if (assetType.Equals("HSE"))
                {
                    data = new Simulator.JsonProps
                    {
                        machineId = thingNo,
                        trendValues = hseDataList.ToArray(),
                        messageId = dateValue + "@" + thingNo,
                        scheduleDate = DateTime.UtcNow
                    };
                }
                if(assetType.Equals("Spotlight_Comp"))
                {
                    data = new Simulator.JsonProps
                    {
                        machineId = thingNo,
                        trendValues = compDataList.ToArray(), //problem is here!, every time the program runs the list grows in size instead of staying the same size each time it executes
                        messageId = dateValue + "@" + thingNo,
                        scheduleDate = DateTime.UtcNow
                    };
                }
                if(assetType.Equals("CPI"))
                {
                    data = new Simulator.JsonProps
                    {
                        machineId = thingNo,
                        trendValues = cpiDataList.ToArray(),
                        messageId = dateValue + "@" + thingNo,
                        scheduleDate = DateTime.UtcNow
                    };
                }
                string jsonOutput = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, Formatting.Indented);
                Console.WriteLine("Publishing JSON to broker for " + assetType);

                switch (assetType)
                {
                    case "Spotlight_Comp":
                        tcompChannel.BasicPublish(exchange: "DataEx",
                                         routingKey: "",
                                         basicProperties: null,
                                         body: Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonOutput));
                        break;
                    case "HSE":
                        thseChannel.BasicPublish(exchange: "DataEx",
                                         routingKey: "",
                                         basicProperties: null,
                                         body: Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonOutput));
                        break;
                    case "CPI":
                        tcpiChannel.BasicPublish(exchange: "DataEx",
                                         routingKey: "",
                                         basicProperties: null,
                                         body: Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonOutput));
                        break;

                }

                Console.WriteLine("Done publishing...");

            }
            Console.WriteLine("Done sending data for all assets..." + "\nWaiting to run again...");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the code for the class that is receiving the values that will be used in the json message.

```
    public class Simulator
    {

        public class JsonProps
        {
            public string machineId { get; set; }
            public SimulatedData[] trendValues { get; set; }
            public string messageId { get; set; }
            public DateTime scheduleDate { get; set; }
        }
        public class SimulatedData
        {
            public decimal value { get; set; }
            public string units { get; set; }
            public string tag { get; set; }
            public string name { get; set; }
        }

    }
```

I am not sure if the issue has to do with the list being static or not. But this issue has stumped me to be honest. If anyone has some input or guidance on how to run this program and keep the list the same size but with different values after each execution that would help me immensely!

Comment: `SetCompValues` keeps adding more items to the `static` list via `.Add`, that is why your list keeps growing, you never `Clear()` it or set it to a `new List()` before calling `SetCompValues`

Comment: I would recommend `new List()` instead of `Clear()`.. causes more issues when you have other variables referencing it

Comment: So when I call CompChannelValueMatching() , should I use compDataList = new List<SimulatedData>();

Answer (score 1):

After Your get array, clear list

```
data = new Simulator.JsonProps
{
    machineId = thingNo,
    trendValues = compDataList.ToArray(), //problem is here!, every time the program runs the list grows in size instead of staying the same size each time it executes
    messageId = dateValue + "@" + thingNo,
    scheduleDate = DateTime.UtcNow
};
compDataList.Clear(); //add this to resolve your Problem
```

Comment: I think i like the compDataList.Clear() approach. Instead of having to declare a new List<SimulatedData>();